# string manipulation with %s format

Tags: c

May you explain the following output:

```
main()
{
   char f[] = "qwertyuiopasd";
   printf("%s\n", f + f[6] - f[8]);
   printf("%s", f + f[4] - f[8]);
}
```

output:

```
uiopasd
yuiopasd
```

For example regarding the first `printf`:

`f[8]` should represent the char `'o'`

`f[6]` should represent the char `'u'`

`%s` format prints the string (`printf("%s", f)` is giving the whole `"qwertyuiopasd"`)

So how does it come together, what is the byte manipulation here?

Comment: Try writing printf("%d\n",f); printf("%d\n",f+f[6]-f[8]); It should be much easier to understand (One char is one byte).

Comment: Hint: `f[6] - f[8] = 'u' - 'o' = 6` because character codes are contiguous and `u` is the 6th character after `o`. So `f + f[6] - f[8] = f + 6`.

Comment: @dxiv IIRC, the C Standard doesn't *dictate* that letter codes should be contiguous (unlike numerical digits). But they nearly always are.

Comment: @Adrian Right, for reference here is a link to [N1570 #5.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1) where that is specified. However, given the quoted output, OP's implementation likely uses ASCII (or perhaps UTF-8) like most implementations do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the characters follows the ASCII scheme, the ASCII value of the following characters are :

```
o (f[8]): 111
u (f[6]): 117
t (f[4]): 116
```

`f` is the pointer to the char[], the first statement values to `f + 6`, this pointer will point to the 6th element of the array, and on printing, it will print from the sixth element till the point it encounters `\0`.

Similarly, the second statement evaluates to `f + 5`, thus you get `yuiopasd` as output.

**What does `f + n` means?**

You can perform the following arithmetic on the pointers ++, --, +, -. The pointer stores the memory address, and the increment operator on a pointer will increase the address value by the size of the type.

for eg for an integer, if `f` points to address location 1000, and we are storing 4 bytes int in the array, then `f + 1` will point to 1004, which is the next element in the array.

Comment: "*Every character has an ASCII value*": it doesn't have to have. And, the expression `f + f[6] - f[8]` is undefined behaviour when it does, given the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin, well spotted. I was just trying to answer the output which the user got.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please explain what do you mean by `"Every character has an ASCII value": it doesn't have to have` ?

Comment: The encoding of characters isn't guaranteed to be ASCII by the C Standard. C doesn't rely on any specific character encoding.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin I got the issue, I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems in the code posted:

- the missing return type for `main` is an obsolete syntax. you should use `int main()`.
- the prototype for `printf` is not in scope when the calls are compiled. This has undefined behavior. You should include `<stdio.h>`.
- the expression `f + f[6] - f[8]` has undefined behavior: addition is left associative, so `f + f[6] - f[8]` is evaluated as `(f + f[6]) - f[8]`. `f[6]`, which is the letter `u` is unlikely to have a value less than 14 (in ASCII, its value is `117`) so `f + f[6]` points well beyond the end of the string, thus is an invalid pointer and computing `f + f[6] - f[8]` has undefined behavior, in spite of the fact that `'u' - 'o'` has the value `6` for the ASCII character set. The expression should be changed to `f + (f[6] - f[8])`.

Assuming ASCII, the letters `o`, `u` and `t` have values `111`, `117` and `116`.
`f + (f[6] - f[8])` is `f + ('u' - 'o')` which is `f + (117 - 111)` or `f + 6`.

`f + 6` is the address of `f[6]`, hence a pointer to the 7th character of the string `"qwertyuiopasd"`. Printing this string produces `uiopasd`.

Answer (score 1):

it is a simple pointer arithmetic which will be easier to understand with this example

```
int main(void)
{
   char f[] = "9876543210";
   printf("%s , f[6]=%d, f[8]=%d, f[6]-f[8]=%d, f + f[6] - f[8] = %s\n",f, f[6], f[8], f[6]-f[8], f + f[6] - f[8]);
```

The result is :

```
9876543210 , f[6]=51, f[8]=49, f[6]-f[8]=2, f + f[6] - f[8] = 76543210
```

`f[n]` is the integer value of the `n`th index element of the array.

In this example the difference between ASCII codes of the 6th and 8th elements is `2`.

When we add `2` to the char pointer it will reference the element `2` chars ahead which in our case is `'7'`

Answer (score 1):

This is all about pointer arithmetic. The expression `f + f[6] - f[8]` evaluates to a `char*` pointer (like its first operand, because the name of an array variable is syntactically equivalent to a pointer to its first element), and will expand to this:

```c
f + (int)'u' - (int)'o'
```

(where 'u' and 'o' represent `f[6]` and `f[8]`, respectively).

The values that represent the characters, `'u'` and `'o'`, are (on almost all modern systems, which use the ASCII system), separated by `6`, so the expression adds `6` to the `f` address and prints the string starting from its 7<sup>th</sup> element.

Similarly for the expression `f + f[4] - f[8]` - but here, the difference is only 5 (`'t' - 'o'`).

Comment: The problem is that the expression `f + f[6] - f[8]` is undefined behaviour unless the value of `f[6]` is less than or equal to the number of elements of the array `f`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Yes, indeed - well spotted. However, in my defence, I was simply explaining why the OP gets the output they do: although the behaviour is not defined by the standard, the used pointer arithmetic does work in their case.